React Native CLI. Build from app store crash , after build from TestFlight
I am a beginner in React Native. I redesigned an application using React Native, but the first version was not built with React Native.
Currently, I have:
Version 1, which is available for download from the App Store.
Version 2, which is distributed via TestFlight.
I am facing an issue when I try to download and open Version 1 on my device. If TestFlight is installed (or has ever been installed on the device), Version 1 fails to open. The app downloads successfully, but when I try to open it, it immediately crashes.
I have already deleted all builds and TestFlight, restarted the device, and then re-downloaded Version 1 from the App Store.
This issue occurs only on devices where TestFlight or App version 2 is (or has ever been) installed, and it happens exclusively on iOS.
How can I fix it?
